# C++: Is self-assignment check required when overloading operator+= and operator-=?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Is a self assignment check, example below, required when overloading `operator+=` and `operator-=`?

Example:

```
class A
{
     A operator+=(const A& a)
     {
         if(this != &a)
         {
             // operations
         }

         return *this;
     }
}
```

Comment: It depends entirely on what needs to happen to add a thing to itself. If failure to account for it would break the operation, then check. If not, then there is no need.

Comment: @Dúthomhas Can you give any more details here?

Comment: It is hard to give details for every possible thing that may be represented, but I'll post an actual answer below that might help.

Answer (score 5):

> Is a self assignment check, as exampled below, required when overloading the operaators += and -= in C++?

No, it is not. In fact, it seems wrong to do so.

It is perfectly legal and semantically valid to use:

```
int i = 10;
i += i;
```

The expectation here is that `i` will be set to `20` at the end of that operation.

Answer (score 3):

> Is a self assignment check, as exampled below, required when overloading the operaators `+=` and `-=` in C++?

No it's not required, it's even wrong. The self check applies the wrong semantics here. Why shouldn't it be possible to add `A` to itself?

Think about an example with a custom string class:

```
MyString s = "abc";
s += s;
```

What would an innocent reader expect as the value of `s`? `"abc"` or `"abcabc"`?

---

Also the operator should return a reference to the current instance:

```
    A& operator+=(const A& a) {
  // ^ ...
    }
```

Comment: Why should it be impossible to allocate A to itself considering this argument?

Comment: @user3728501 I don't understand your question?

Comment: And why should one return a reference?

Comment: Well, usually you add this check to `operator=` to prevent self-assignment. Why?

Comment: @user3728501 Check the [canonical](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/1413395) please, section Binary arithmetic operators in particular.

Comment: It isn't wrong if adding a thing to itself is not possible without immutable sources.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're mucking with the internal state of the object, it might be necessary to do a "self check" in order to make sure to access the object consistently, but it isn't a self assignment check. `a += a` certainly shouldn't result in `a` being unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

The self assignment test, e.g. `if (this != &a)` is normally done for assignment operator `operator=(const A& s)` for efficiency reasons or to avoid using destroyed data if the operator destroys some members before doing actual assignment. However, even there it is normally indicator of a design problem.

As for `operator+=` and `operator-=` it is not required, and what is more, it would be a problem to use it! For e.g. integers, if `x == 2`

```
x += x;
```

should change `x` to 4. In your classes you should keep the same behaviour: `a += a;` definitely should modify `a`.

Comment: Damn... I thought there was a serious need for `if(this != &a)` in `operator=`... Why do people bother with it? Okay for efficiency... but when exactly are you likely to encounter assignment of an instance of `class A` to itself? Seems like a silly reason to add this check...

Comment: Note: Usually required if object manages a resource. You don't want to `delete[]` the data and then try to copy it!

Comment: @user3728501 Normally you would not write `x = x`, but when you write `x = some_function_returning_existing_object_from_some_container()` then it may happen. And it is not only done for efficiency - some weakly designed classes can e.g. destroy its data before assignment, so for self assignment it would mean using deleted data.

Comment: @user3728501 I modified the answer to include situation with `delete[]`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on what it means to "add" your objects. Since your question seems to be of a general nature (where addition may be any operation that can be combined with assignment), I can, off the top of my head, only think of an example with multiplication.

With [bignums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) the multiplication process cannot be done in-place. The destination object must be distinct from the source(s). If not, the multiplication will fail.

I admit that the example isn't perfect. Often, you can avoid asking the question about self-assignment by forcing the issue. A bignum multiply-assign might look like this:

```
bignum& operator += ( bignum& lhs, const bignum& rhs )
{
  return lhs.swap( lhs + rhs );  // lhs = lhs + rhs
}
```

This leverages the existing operator+ to perform the multiplication to create a temporary result, which is then assigned intelligently using the bignum's `swap()` member function (it has one, right?).

Again, this was just an example off the top of my head... and not a perfect one. There might arise situations (and you know how your data is manipulated best) that require a different strategy.

[edit] The good example of avoiding calling `delete[]` on a resource was made above. [/edit]

**tl;dr**

If you *need* to check for self assignment, do it.
If you don't, then don't.